# Store output of command with error

Tags: powershell

I want to store the output of this command
`git checkout master`

the output of this command has two states.

1. success - the command outputs:

   > Switched to branch 'X'
2. failure -  the command outputs

   > Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout <list files> : Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches. Aborting

I want to store the output and check if it succeeds by checking for the string abort.

This is what I've tried.

```
$output = git checkout master 2>&1
if ($output.Contains("Aborting")) {
    Write-Host $output -BackgroundColor Red
} else {
    Write-Host $output
}
```

but `$output` produces something like this, when in the second state:

[image]

It seems like the command completed, but it was the wrong syntax. How do I fix this? I would like to to ouput

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your command's stderr output is converted to regular strings:

```
$output = [string[]] (git checkout master 2>&1)
```

Without the `[string[]]` cast, stderr output lines are stored in `$output` as `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances, and outputting such instances later somewhat misleadingly prints them as if they were PowerShell errors.

(Note that PowerShell *Core* no longer exhibits this behavior: while stderr lines are still *captured* as `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances, they now *print* as regular strings.)